# Language needed for a web task

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have a question about the type of web coding language I would need to complete a few specific tasks:

- The script needs to be able to import from a text or MySQL database which has hundreds of entries (call this database.txt)
- It needs to be able to have some way of taking each line of database.txt and storing it as a string to a variable, which then can be used by the script
- It should be able to return some text(not to the user, only to the script) in the form of something you'd see at this URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=stackoverflow&:)&since:2011-05-11&rpp=100&page=15
- It needs to have some way of searching the text returned for a certain string (in the above URL, say `<published>`) in order to tally the amount of entries that the document contains
- It also needs to be able to export the information it accumulates to a database so it's able to be shown to the end-user by PHP
- Preferably it should be able to run in the background without the person viewing the results having to see or wait for any of the processing, maybe running once a day

My question essentially is, what language would I need to use to accomplish all of the above tasks and making them automated?

Comment: All programming languages can perform the above tasks...

Comment: You can do this with any language your server supports (e.g. PHP/Ruby/Python) and use a cron job to run the script(s) once a day.

Comment: You tagged as PHP so are you asking if PHP will work? You can do all this in PHP. For the record you could do this in almost any language, some popular ones right now being PHP, Python, and Ruby (in no particular order of importance, and not a complete list!)

Comment: I wasn't really sure if PHP could do what I need, but I'm glad there are other options too - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question essentially is, what language would I need to use to accomplish all of the above tasks and making them automated?

Any programming language. Use the one you know best if you need to get this done quickly. Use the one you want to learn next if learning a new language is more important then getting this done soon.